# Don't return ToString, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType with Type.GetMethods()

Tags: c#, reflection, methods

Given some classes like this:

```
public class MyBaseClass()
{
    public void MyMethodOne()
    {
    }

    public virtual void MyVirtualMethodOne()
    {
    }
}

public class MyMainClass : MyBaseClass()
{
    public void MyMainClassMethod()
    {
    }

    public override void MyVirtualMethodOne()
    {
    }
}
```

If I run the following:

```
var myMethods= new MyMainClass().GetType().GetMethods();
```

I get back:

- MyMethodOne
- MyVirtualMethodOne
- MyMainClassMethod
- ToString
- Equals
- GetHashCode
- GetType

How can I avoid the last 4 methods being returned in `myMethods`

- ToString
- Equals
- GetHashCode
- GetType

**EDIT**

So far, this hack is working, but was wondering if there was a cleaner way:

```
        var exceptonList = new[] { "ToString", "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType" };
        var methods = myInstanceOfMyType.GetType().GetMethods()
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .Except(exceptonList);
```

Comment: You can use [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) to only get `MyMainClassMethod` and `MyVirtualMethodOne`, but I don't think there's a corresponding flag for "methods declared down to, but not including, those in `object`".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You also can do the trick:

```
var methods = typeof(MyMainClass)
                    .GetMethods()
                    .Where(m => !typeof(object)
                                     .GetMethods()
                                     .Select(me => me.Name)
                                     .Contains(m.Name));
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use

```
var myMethods = new MyMainClass().GetType().GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.DeclaringType != typeof(object));
```

you will discard those bottom four methods, unless they have been overridden somewhere in your heirarchy.

(I'd want this behaviour myself, but if you want those four excluded *whatever*, then Cuong's answer will do this.)

Comment: Upvoted for returning them, however in this case I wanted to exclude them altogether

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
GetMethods().Where((mi)=> mi.DeclaringType != typeof(object));
```

With a little bit of LINQ, you can eliminate all the methods declared in `object` class.

Comment: This isn't what he wants - this will only give two of the three methods.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to use `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`. (These first three are the flags used by the `GetMethods()` overload.)

Comment: `GetMethods().Where((mi)=> mi.DeclaringType != typeof(object));` How bout now ?

Comment: Yes, now you've taken my answer :)

Comment: Sorry man.. I noticed your answer later... I guess your answer is more complete..

Comment: There's no reason to use strike over on the text. That's what the version history is for!

Answer (score -2):

We can also exclude them explicitly:

```
public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetMethodsWithoutStandard(this Type t)
        {
            var std = new List<string>() {  nameof(ToString),
                                            nameof(Equals),
                                            nameof(GetHashCode),
                                            nameof(GetType)};
            return t.GetMethods().Where(x => !std.Contains(x.Name));
        }
```

This approach is not afraid of overwriting of these methods